# Face API - Error 404 during Person Group PUT operation

Tags: node.js, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition

I try to use face api by using js node but the response is always "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" is there something I should miss when installing?

this my code

```
const uriBase2 = 'https://myendpoint/face/v1.0/persongroups';

const params = {
    'personGroupId': 'dava12345',
};

const options = {
    uri: uriBase2,
    qs: params,
    method: 'PUT',
    body: '{ "name": "group2", "userData": "user-provided data attached to ", "recognitionModel": "recognition_02" }',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : 'mykey'
    }
};


 request(options, (error, response, body) => {
     if (error) {
       console.log('Error: ', error);
       return;
     }
     let jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, '  ');
     console.log('JSON Response\n');
     console.log(jsonResponse);
   });
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, it looks like you should supply the `personGroupId` like this `http://myendpoint/face/v1.0/persongroups/{personGroupId}`. It should not be passed in as querystring parameters.

Comment: This request method should be `GET`.

Comment: @Jason not if the OP is trying to create his/her person group (which seems to be the target as he/she is passing user data and recognition values): it's a PUT operation in that case https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244

Comment: @NicolasR Tks, I get it ,and  I find the problem and solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I find the issue. You just lose `/` in your request url and need to add `params.personGroupId` after `uriBase`.

*Error pic:*

[image]

*Correct pic:*

[image]

List personGroup, find `202006090101` which created just now.

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

***Code:***

```
const request = require('request');

const uriBase = 'https://ea***s.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups';

const params = {
    'personGroupId': 'pan***test',
};

const options = {
    url: uriBase,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : '6e4f6d73***23ddf2f5792'
    }
};

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    let json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
});
```

***Pic:***

[image]

***Details:***

1. Create Project folder, open with vscode
2. Create a `test.js` file in folder, paste my test code and replace `uriBase`，`personGroupId` and `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`.
3. run `npm i`, when success, then run `npm install request`
4. run `node test.js`